# What is a better alternative to .next() and .prev() when multiple elements are present?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery for a set of voting buttons.

When the up votes is clicked the down vote is deselected and vice versa.

Currently I am using `$(this).next();` to get the down vote that is next to the up vote and `$(this).prev();` for the up vote when clicking the down vote.

I need a good alternative that would allow me to add other html elements around and close by these two elements without having to worry about the position of the up and down vote breaking jQuery.

There are multiple up and down votes on a page.

Any solutions or ideas?

Example:

```
<div class="heart btn pull-right click-heart peinto-heart-empty" data-is-clicked="false" data-sketch-id="someid"></div>

<div class="poop btn pull-right click-poop peinto-poop-empty" data-is-clicked="false" data-sketch-id="someid"></div>
```

Comment: Any code or demo are welcome :).

Comment: name your buttons with specific classes; i.e. `.voteDown, .voteUp` then just say `$(this).find('.voteUp')` or `$(this).find('.voteDown')`

Comment: The documentation is usually the first place to look for an answer: [jQuery Tree Traversal](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/). In particular look into the `siblings()` method.

Comment: Please post your relevant code and if possible a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsFiddle) demonstrating your issue. Without any code it will be impossible to give you concrete examples on what you might try. Aside from alternatives to `prev()/next()` you can use classes or even data attributes if you want to have even more flexibility over multiple instances of button sets, similar to `data-id="up-vote"` and you might even give the container of those voting buttons a `data-id="guid"` and give the voting buttons a `data-parent-id="guidFromParent"` for context or something completely different.

Comment: As a side note, your selectors should be as close to accurate as possible for obvious performance reasons. If your current implementation of `prev()` and `next()` work that is good. Your HTML structure should not really change that often. On the rare occasion it changes it is natural to update your selectors, which should be easy when using well formed JavaScript in which all your selectors are grouped, possibly even at the top of your JavaScript module/class concerned with voting. If you want to write selectors to cover future scenarios you may end up with extremely ill performing selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that the upvote and downvote buttons are within the same parent element (this will still work if they share a common non-immediate parent that the other upvote/downvote buttons do not share, but the code is a little messier):

```
<div class="voting-box">
    <button class="upvote" ... >Up!</button>
    <button class="downvote" ... >Down!</button>
</div>
```

Then we have an on-click handler for upvote:

```
function onUpvoteClick(event) {
    var downvoteButton = $(event.target).parent().find('.downvote');
    // do something with the downvote button, eg:
    downvoteButton.css('color', 'red');
}
```

If we add more elements to the `.voting-box` or change the order of the elements within, this code will still work.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bxLyM/

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like this

```
Item 1
<a class="vote" data-id="1" data-direction="up">Vote Up</a>
<a class="vote" data-id="1" data-direction="down">Vote Down</a>

<br>

Item 2
<a class="vote" data-id="2" data-direction="up">Vote Up</a>
<a class="vote" data-id="2" data-direction="down">Vote Down</a>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('a.vote').click(function(e) {
    var id = $(this).data('id');

    //save the vote (via ajax)

    $('a.vote[data-id="' + id + '"]').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
});
```

Here is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krisdahl/y7hCn/)